# How to restrict Javascript events to a container?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, mouseover, restriction

How would I restrict these mouse events to a container?

I need the mouse events to only affect the script when it is over my canvas, not when it is in other parts of the browser window.

I am a bit new to this so I apologize if this is very simple.

```
document.addEventListener('mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false);
document.addEventListener('touchstart', onDocumentTouchStart, false);
document.addEventListener('touchmove', onDocumentTouchMove, false);
//
window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);
}

function onWindowResize() {
    windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
    windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
}
//
function onDocumentMouseMove(event) {
    mouseX = event.clientX - windowHalfX;
    mouseY = event.clientY - windowHalfY;
}

function onDocumentTouchStart(event) {
    if (event.touches.length > 1) {
        event.preventDefault();
        mouseX = event.touches[0].pageX - windowHalfX;
        mouseY = event.touches[0].pageY - windowHalfY;
    }
}

function onDocumentTouchMove(event) {
    if (event.touches.length == 1) {
        event.preventDefault();
        mouseX = event.touches[0].pageX - windowHalfX;
        mouseY = event.touches[0].pageY - windowHalfY;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most straightforward way to fix this would be to have your script hook up the event listener to your `canvas` object and not the `document` object.  Then, you will simply not get any mouse or touch messages when the event is not happening over the canvas.

If, for some reason, that isn't practical, then you can check every `event.target` with some common code to see if the event originated over a canvas object and just not do anything with the event if it's not over a canvas object.

---

Also, the code you posted has an extraneous `}` in it after the fourth event listener.

Comment: This worked, but only vertically. There are still mouse messages when I move horizontally for the entire width of the browser.

Comment: @nballiett - That's probably because your canvas object extends the whole width of the browser window.  If you could make a jsFiddle that shows the issue, we could help more thoroughly.  Right now, you're making us guess what your HTML looks like.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/faL91Ldt/4/                               I tried to get it to work on there but it doesnt seem it be. I don't know why.

Comment: @nballiett - The browser is blocking the loading of your scripts from `http://` instead of `https://` in the jsFiddle because the jsFiddle window where your script runs is itself `https`.  I don't know how to work around that in a jsFiddle.  FYI, the HTML you put in the jsFiddle is missing a closing `</div>`.  And, if your canvas object is indeed just a regular `div`, that will by default go the whole width of the window (as do all block elements).  You could assign it a width to restrict it to a particular width.

Comment: <div id="canvas" style="width:500px;">
     </div>

Comment: @nballiett - That will work.  I'd suggest using CSS instead `#canvas {width: 500px;}`.

Comment: The css doesnt work either. It just adds text to the top of the screen.

Comment: @nballiett - FYI, you can temporarily assign a 1px border to your canvas div so you can see its actual size in the page.

Comment: I must be doing something incorrectly so that the js is not actually in the div

Comment: @nballiett - The JS you showed in your question does not have to be "inside" the div.  It needs to be somewhere after the div.

Comment: Okay, it works now, im not sure what I did but what you said worked exactly. Thank you!